# issue with output of c code related to union concept

Tags: c, unions

my code is as follows:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    union a {
        short int x;
        char y[2];
    };
    union a e;
    e.y[0] = 3;
    e.y[1] = 2;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", e.y[0], e.y[1], e.x);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives output as

```
3
2
515
```

i didn't understand that how this 515 comes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I wanted an excuse for ASCII art...

Declaring the `union` lets you choose how to interpret its data.  In your case, either as an `unsigned short` or a `char [2]`.  Both of these are 2 bytes long, so your union will refer to a 2-byte section of memory, thusly:

```
union a e;

    ---------------
e-> | ???? | ???? |
    ---------------
```

Now you decide to interpret your union as a character array:

```
e.y[0] = 3;

    ---------------
e-> | 0x03 | ???? |
    ---------------

e.y[1] = 2;

    ---------------
e-> | 0x03 | 0x02 |
    ---------------
```

Then you interpret it as an `unsigned short`:

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", e.y[0], e.y[1], e.x);
```

You're on a little-endian system (as @Oli noted), meaning the least-significant byte is stored first in memory.  Which means that when your code looks at an `unsigned short`, it thinks `0x03` is the *least-significant* byte.

So your 2-byte unsigned short is interpreted as `0x0203`.  And `0x0203` hex is `515` decimal.

---

That comment was interesting enough to put in the answer for clarity, I think.

Let's say we do this:

```
union a {
    int x;
    char y[2];
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    union a e = {512};
}
```

What's inside? Break it down:

`int` is 4 bytes, `char [2]` is 2 bytes, so the `union` is 4 bytes long to store the largest datatype.  `512` is `0x00000200` in hex.  So store that integer little-endian and you have:

```
    -----------------------------
e-> | 0x00 | 0x02 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
    -----------------------------
```

So `e.x` is 512. `e.y[0]` is 0 and `e.y[1]` is 2

Comment: then, if union have 
union a { int x, char y[2] };
union a e = {512};
then what is the value of all members?

Comment: Is this a test? ;)  I'll bite.  `int` is 4 bytes, and `512` is `0x00000200` as an integer.  So store that integer little-endian and you have `[00][02][00][00]` in memory.  So `e.x` is 512.  `e.y[0]` is `0` and `y[1]` is `2`.  What do I win?

Answer (score 3):

The 515 is hex 0x0203.

e.y[0] is 3, or 0x03.
e.y[1] is 2, or 0x02.

The short int x combines the two into 0x0203, or 515.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system:

2 * 2<sup>8</sup> + 3 = 515.

The union is effectively allowing you to reinterpret the memory used by the `short` as a pair of consecutive `char`s.

Comment: can you please explain the expression that you wrote ?

Comment: @HiteshJhamb: A `short` is 2 bytes on your platform.  A byte is 8 bits.  Therefore the upper byte is worth 2^8 = 256 times as much as the lower byte.

Comment: As union creates space of maximum sized member space that is 2 bytes.
So when we put 3 and 2 in y[0], y[1] respectively then 3 stores in first byte as 00000011 and in second byte it stores as 00000010 then how you relate this with your expression?

Comment: @algoh: Because the 16-bit quantity is 0000001000000011, or 2 << 8 + 3, or 2 * 2^8 + 3.